# How to turn each word in a string in a list into elements in a list

Tags: python

I would like to turn each word in a string in a list into elements in a list

Example:

```
    Input: l = ["the train was late", "I looked for mary and sam at the bus station"]

    Output: l = ["the","train","was","late","I","looked","for","mary","and","sam","at","the","bus","station"]
```

I tried doing this:

```
   l = []
   for word in data_txt_file:
       s = word.split(" ")
       l.append(s)
```

But then I get:

```
    Output: l = [["the","train","was","late",],["I","looked","for","mary","and","sam","at","the","bus","station"]]
```

Maybe from here I can just remove the nested lists and flatten it, however, can I just I immediately go there, instead of doing like this middle step with splitting it.

Comment: Use extend rather than append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way to go with the current code itself is to make use of the `extend` methods provided to lists:

```
   l = []
   for word in data_txt_file:
       s = word.split(" ")
       l.extend(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be to transform the first list to a single string, so you can just tokenize it as a whole:

`l = ' '.join(data_txt_file).split(' ')`

Or, you could just flatten the nested list you got in your solution:

```
l2 = []
for e in l: l2+=e
```

This would also result in a list that just has the words as elements.

Or, if you really want to make this word by word as in your first solution:

```
l = []
for line in data_txt_file:
    for word in line.split(' '):
        l.append(word)
```

Comment: If you only split on `' '`, you'll end up with loads of embedded newlines. There is also no need to create an intermediate string. The easiest solution is simply `l = list(data_txt_file.read().split())`.

Comment: Agreed. No matter what you do, this tokenizer will produce lots of artifacts. I just offered solutions for this first step. Punctuation, empty tokens, etc. will continue to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single line of code:

```
l = ",".join(l).replace(",", " ").split(" ")
```

Output: ['the', 'train', 'was', 'late', 'I', 'looked', 'for', 'mary', 'and', 'sam', 'at', 'the', 'bus', 'station']